# Let n be a positive integer. Determine the number of ordered pairs (a, b) of positive integers with lcm(a, b) = n as a function of τ .

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions

I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

I know that the arithmetic tau function denotes the number of positive divisors of n.

Comment: I suggest you start by writing out the cases $n = 1 ... 18$ and see if you notice a pattern, or any relation between $\tau(n)$ and the number $d(n)$ of pairs. When you've done that, and thought about some patterns, add it to your question, and maybe we'll be able to help you make another step.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the prime factorization of $n$ is $\prod_j p_j^{v_j}$ and that
of  $a$  is  $\prod_j  p_j^{v_{j,1}}$  and that  of  $b$  is  $\prod_j
p_j^{v_{j,2}}.$ Then we must have $\max(v_{j,1}, v_{j,2}) = v_j.$ That
means either they are both equal  to $v_j$ (one possibility) or one is
$v_j$  and the other  one is  less than  $v_j$ including  zero ($2v_j$
possibilities).   Therefore $p_j$ contributes  $2v_j+1$ possibilities,
the same as  the contribution of $p_j$ to the  divisor count of $n^2.$
Hence  the answer  is  $\tau(n^2).$ (Recall  that  $\tau(n) =  \prod_j
(v_j+1).$)